# Translating SQL LIKE to LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL fragment that I cannot figure out how to translate into LINQ

```
(p.prioid LIKE '1%' OR p.prioid LIKE '2%' OR p.prioid LIKE '3%')
```

I attempted this:

```
(p.prioid.Contains(1) || p.prioid.Contains(2) || p.prioid.Contains(3))
```

but receive the following error message: "cannot convert from int to string"

I checked the table and the 1, 2, and 3 are int data types so I don't think it would work properly if I converted the ints to strings by placing quotation marks.

Comment: You need to convert the integer type to string (`.ToString()`) before you perform any string comparison operations ([ICompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIKE will only work using string data provided, even if you are searching in other datatypes.

if you notice, even in SQL, you are submitting them as strings.

```
p.prioid LIKE '1%' OR p.prioid LIKE '2%' OR p.prioid LIKE '3%'
```

a quick fix will be using `.ToString()` and submit your query.

```
(p.prioid.Contains(1.ToString()) || p.prioid.Contains(2.ToString()) || p.prioid.Contains(3.ToString()))
```

I guess this will be using some sort of variables rather than fixed values like the example.

Comment: @ Mohammed ElSayed: <I>down vote accept
 

LIKE will only work using string data provided. even if you are searching in other datatypes.

if you notice, even in SQL, you are submitting them as strings.</I>. You are correct.  I didn't even notice that. I was fixated on the fact that prioid is an int datatype.  This causes even more confusion.  If the data field is an int but the SQL statement is looking for a string, how can that work?  Also, is there a difference between doing a "p.prioid.Contains(1.ToString())"  and doing p.prioid.Contains("1")?

Comment: There will be no difference between these 2 examples, because they will evaluate to the same SQL statement.
P.S: what is Down Vote Accept? did you do so or someone else.
by the way we are all here to help each other, and we all are going to say some wrong info or will face something that we don't know.
so no worries, I just tried to help you. glade that you have solved your problem.

Comment: I don't know what Down Vote Accept means.  I clicked "this answer is useful" and clicked the check mark as my accepted answer.  You did not say anything wrong or give me any wrong info.  On the contrary, you were very helpful and I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Mo a slip of the mouse to the left while text-selecting your first two sentences will include the downvote and accept UI elements in one's selection. If you look at the page source, you will see that the text of these two elements is 'downvote' and 'accept'. If you then paste your selection, those two words will be included...

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: Thank you for the Answer mark, I hope that I was that helpful for you.

Comment: @ AakashM and @ Mohammed ElSayed - I see what Mo was talking about now.  I didn't notice that phrase was included in my my cut and paste and if you had not commented I would have had no idea what Mo was talking about it.  Thank you very much for clearing that up.  I will ensure that I do not cut and paste comments anymore.  Mr. ElSayed I can assure you it was not done on purpose and I meant no disrespect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(p.prioid.ToString().StartsWith("1") || p.prioid.ToString().StartsWith("2") || p.prioid.ToString().StartWith("3"))
```

Quick-n-dirty :)